# get_file() got multiple values for argument "fname"

Tags: google-colaboratory, file-management, getfiles

Does someone know why this error is happening as I have the right name for the internal folder?

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_file
import os
import pathlib

!mkdir -p Test

os.path.join("content/test")
get_file("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6", fname="data", untar=True)
```

I'm trying to import a set of data in Colab into a folder called Test, but the get_file function does not work for some reason.

Here is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-fd1d2dd17137> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 
      3 os.path.join("content/test")
----> 4 get_file("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6", fname="data", untar=True)

TypeError: get_file() got multiple values for argument 'fname'
```

I tried changing the folder names, messing around with the fname part but nothing worked.

Comment: Use the argument 'original' and provide URL value for that, I mean: get_file(origin ="url", fname = "filename", , untar=True)